# The image is "from disk cache", but still have "content download" time in timeline

Tags: javascript, image, browser-cache

System: macOS Sierra

Browser: Chrome(Version=55)

Image size: 809KB

This image is "from disk cache", but "content download" spend 869ms

Http status is 200, means browser use client cache so there is no need to download image content.

I'm so confused, thanks for any help on a proper direction.

[image: This is snap in chrome]

Comment: Chrome is the king of the caching. A very poor cache. It always breaks my balls. When I develop with chrome, I always press CTRL+F5 several times before the real content is downloaded. Long live to chrome craps!

Comment: However, 200 status code is an OK, that means that the content will be downloaded. Maybe you are refering to 304 code

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does Chrome spend time “downloading” content from cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250802/why-does-chrome-spend-time-downloading-content-from-cache)

Comment: @OlegGrishko ok, i understand, so the "Content Downloaded" time is just retrieve and decompress time. But it cost too much...

Comment: I hope that the article is helpful for you。[why-does-chrome-spend-time-downloading-content-from-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250802/why-does-chrome-spend-time-downloading-content-from-cache)

Comment: @gaopeng Thank you.