# Browser shows previous response

Tags: go, liteide

I run the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sroot)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func sroot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome")
}
```

and browser showed a response as expected: `Welcome`
then, after some time I try to change the output but have found that the output does not change! so, when I change the output  `fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome 123")` but browser still ouptuts `Welcome`.

So what's the magic happens here?

Comment: did you restart the server after changes?

Comment: I restarted a program, but how to restart a server? And I run it from IDE.

Comment: which one IDE are you  using ?

Comment: @saddam I'm using LiteIDE and I run the file via Alt+F6

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ updated an answer, follow that.

Comment: @saddam seems it doesn't work

Comment: The answer of @dan-esparza is likely to be correct, you can check this question to see how to debug if the browser used cache or not in chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140318/check-whether-network-response-is-coming-from-server-or-chrome-cache

Comment: @thst disabling a browser cache does not solve the issue, but I was able to run it with different port adress, but againe if I want to change the output even with the new port adress the response does not change.

Comment: @user8049659 there would be a refresh icon on IDE which will restart the server, try it.

Comment: @user8049659 I tried your code and it works for me in goland. Add a line `log.Print("received call")` in your `sroot` func. This will tell you if there is a cache issue or something other.

Comment: @thst Added it before fmt.Fprintf... restarted, then changed response and again restarted - nothing changed

Comment: You should see the log message for each request. like this `2019/01/02 14:39:05 received call`

Answer (score 2):

By default the browser makes a [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request when navigating to the page.  The browser is also going to make some decisions about the 'cachability' of the page:  Has the url changed?  Has the querystring changed?  Has the [ETAG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) changed?  If none of these are true, the browser is most likely serving a cached version of the page.

Comment: ETag doesn't work like that. The browser doesn't know if the ETag has changed until it makes another request, which will include If-None-Match if the ETag is known. The *server* then gets to decide if it returns 304 Not Modified or new content. Also cacheability is controlled by Cache-Control and Expires.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gin` to reload your webserver.

Installation: `go get github.com/codegangsta/gin`

Usage: `gin run filename.go`

Reference: https://github.com/codegangsta/gin

Comment: Installed it, created folder in `src` named `webserver` and there is a main file, so then I call it `gin run webserver.go` it shows me `[gin] Listening on port 3000 
[gin] Building... 
[gin] ←[97;32;1mBuild finished←[0m` but the browser output is the same as was before even after reloading the browser tab.