# how to caching javascript file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nginx, webpack, pug

[image]I have a large web application that was built about 9-8 years ago with "[pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)" technology, and in recent years pages have been added in an innovative framework (vue.js)
Now in any transition between an old page (pug) and a vue page, the Webpack (version 3.12) loads a build.js file (3.8MB!) that Located in index.html and takes an average of 9 seconds to load and significantly Interferes with the UX.

is there any way I can save the build.js in the cache?
or alternatively, I would love to hear if anyone has another idea that can enhance the user experience

**the webserver of the site is Nginx**

**edit:
here is my nginx file (the relevant parts)**

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xxx.com;
    return 301 https://xxx$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.com;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
      location ~ ^/dist/(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }
    location ~ ^/public/(\d+)/(.+)$ {
         try_files /lbo_builds/build_$1/public/$1/$2 =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/export/data/(.+)$ {
        gzip_static always;
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
        add_header Content-disposition attachment;
        try_files /lbo_exported_files/$1.gz =404;
    }

    location /customer_upload_document_proxy {
        proxy_set_header Cookie JSESSIONID=$cookie_jba_session;
        proxy_pass xxx;
    }

    location / {
        expires off;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://$backend_upstream$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Split the single huge `build.js` into small chunks](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) to take advantage of browser’s parallel downloading.
2. configure gzip compression and cache control with nginx

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name xxx.com;
    return 301 https://xxx$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.com;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location ~ ^/public/(\d+)/(.+)$ {
         try_files /lbo_builds/build_$1/public/$1/$2 =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/export/data/(.+)$ {
        gzip_static always;
        add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
        add_header Content-disposition attachment;
        try_files /lbo_exported_files/$1.gz =404;
    }

    location /customer_upload_document_proxy {
        proxy_set_header Cookie JSESSIONID=$cookie_jba_session;
        proxy_pass xxx;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
        
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://$backend_upstream$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        expires off;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://$backend_upstream$request_uri;
    }


}
```

Comment: Not only because of parallel downloading but mostly because chunks can be lazily imported per need basis.

Comment: I added this code to my Nginx conf file, but it still doing the same slow render.
(the build.sh file is located under the dist folder inside the root)
do you have an idea what I am missing?

"      location ~ ^/dist/(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ "

Comment: You can follow this post to check if the cache take effected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140318/check-whether-network-response-is-coming-from-server-or-chrome-cache

Comment: yes, I checked it, unfortunately it doesn't do caching,

Comment: did you reload nginx after editing the confgure file?

Comment: when i deploy to test env, my script doing reload, so yes.

Comment: Could you update your post to provide nginx conf and http response header in Network tab of Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: updated my answer, you could give it a try.

Comment: my deploy to test env failed (i add bracket it was missing in your snippet code)

Comment: weird,  `^/dist/(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$` in your conf did not match build.js, `~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$` in my conf should work